# Is there a way to figure out what file in GiHub causes the build in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I currently set up Jenkins and GitHub so that when a push is sent to GitHub a build is automatically triggered. Is there a way to get the name of the file that causes the build. For example, if I have a file in GitHub named test.txt in a repo called TestRepo and I commit a change in test.txt, how could I figure out the build was caused by a change in test.txt and not due to another file in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the GitHub plugin for polling, the build will be triggered by a commit/s not by a specific file. You can see the changes log directly in Jenkins in 'Changes' tab or if you need to get the list of files in the pipeline you can try to have a step with something like 'git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT  $GIT_COMMIT' after the checkout step.

Comment: Im using an execute shell build and I need to use the names of the files that have been changed. So i need to know which files caused the builds to run

Comment: Before reaching the build step, how is your Jenkins job automatically triggered, it is not clear for me?

Comment: @lonutS a change is made in GitHub which automatically starts the build in jenkins. So the job is triggered before reaching the build step. I have connected GitHub in SCM and have set it up under build triggers.

Comment: Are you using pipeline or free style job in jenkins?

Comment: free style @lonutS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Groovy script to get the files changed. You can simply retrieve the changeset with `currentBuild.changeSets` and process the changeset as shown below to get the files that changed.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                git (url: 'https://github.com/xxxx/sample.git', branch: 'main')
                script {
                    def changedFiles = getFilesChanged()
                    echo "${changedFiles}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getFilesChanged() {
    def filesList = []
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
                    for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                    def file = files[k]
                    filesList.add(file.path)
            }
        }
    }
    return filesList
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this in a freestyle script?